# Passing a variable into every ejs template with app.use not working

Tags: node.js, express, syntax, ejs

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
next()
})
```

and I am using it in an ejs template like this

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <%  if(currentUser){ %>
            <li><a href="/login">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="/register">Sign Up</a></li>
          <% } else { %>
            <li><a href="#">Signed in as <%= currentUser.username%></a></li>
            <li><a href="/logout">Sign Out</a></li>
          <%}%>

        </ul>
```

Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: Something is going wrong when you are passing `currentUser`

Comment: Are you sure that req.user has a value with a 'username' property? What is populating req.user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass `req.session` in locals and then you can use globally username variable in all `ejs` files

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.username = req.session.username;
    next();
});
```

now you can call in `ejs` files

```
<%= username %>
```